Observations within a level of fixed effect have the same level of random effect
My study aims to compare human performance with model performance on math tasks.
Here's the setup:
There are 700 unique assignments. 6 random human participants were recruited to work ok each assignment.In total, around 400 humans participated. Each participant completed around 10 assignments.
For each assignment, I also got performance results from 2 models.
so, for each assignment, I have performance scores for the 6 human participants and performance scores for the 2 models.
I used mixed linear model to compare human and model's performance. This is the formula in R:
data.model <- lmer(score ~ type + (1 | participant_id) + (1 | assignment_id), data = data_1)
type: Indicates whether the observation is from a human (human) or a model (model).
participant_id: Unique for each human participant. For models, I set participant_id as "model".
assignment_id: Identifies the assignment.
My question is that is it problematic that the random effect participant_id for models has only one level? If so, how could I adjust the model to appropriately compare human and model performance?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How do you account for the fact that there were two different models? One approach is to have three values of type and keep participant_id coded as is. Another is to have unique participant_ids for each of the two models (model1 and model2). In that latter case, you would keep type to two values (human vs. computer).

@ErikRuzek Thanks for pointing that out! Yes, I realized I should account for the two different models. So right now, I have unique participant_id for each of the twos models (model 1 and model 2) and leave type to human and model. But I was concerned about the imbalance in this random_effect, participant_id, as there are around 400 human participants and only 2 models. I am wondering if such imbalance can make the model may overemphasize the variability among human participants while underestimating variability for models.
